How to resolve NO OUTPUT or CHANNEL REPLY HEADER
For a threeway communication between two external applications built with something different and my springboot app

External client 1 always initiates communication via TCP socket
Springboot application uses TCPInboundGateway to receive information
Springboot application uses TCPOutboundGateway to send stuff to external client 2
Response is gotten back from external client 2
I want to send this response to externalClient1
I am getting the no output or channel reply header

I assume that the TcpInboundGateway created in the first instance is a request-reply, so it should wait for the response which is what external client 2 will send to it through my app.
In the service that gets the response from the TcpOutboundGateway, I
assumed that just by setting the outputChannel on this service as      the same name with the replyChannel in the tcpInboundGateway,      then the connection will be made. But this does not work. So why the no output or reply header
 //The inbound gateway
  @Bean
     public TcpInboundGateway 
     tcpInboundGateway(AbstractServerConnectionFactory 
     serverConnectionFactory) {
    TcpInboundGateway gateway = new TcpInboundGateway();
    gateway.setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory);
    gateway.setRequestChannel(requestChannel());
    gateway.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    gateway.setReplyChannel(backToPos());
    gateway.setReplyTimeout(60000);
    return gateway;
}

// The outbound gateway
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "tcpUpslOutgateChannel")
public MessageHandler tcpOutboundGateway() {
    TcpOutboundGateway gateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    gateway.setConnectionFactory(upslClientConnectionFactory());
    gateway.setUnsolicitedMessageChannel(unsolicitedChannel());
    gateway.setOutputChannelName("forUpslReplyChannel");
    return gateway;
}

//Service that handles the response
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "forUpslReplyChannel", 
 outputChannel = "backToPos")
public String 
 processResponseMessageFromUpslForPurchase(Message<String> 
 messageFull) {
   return processResponseMessageForPurchase(messageFull);
}

The other configuration include channels and service handlers...
Below are the logs
024-07-12T08:47:07.307+01:00  INFO 23544 --- [terminal-management] [pool-2-thread-2] c.r.t.s.t.ResponseService                : still in the response service
2024-07-12T08:47:07.311+01:00 DEBUG 23544 --- [terminal-management] [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway           : failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler@25207619]
2024-07-12T08:47:07.311+01:00 ERROR 23544 --- [terminal-management] [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Exception sending message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[809], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=55560, ip_connectionId=127.0.0.1:55560:30002:6a5442c5-0c0d-4217-aab2-fe49776b6d6c, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=c841c491-79dc-5e17-4e95-6f7ac6052b79, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1720770425566}]

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler@25207619]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:108) 
        at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:206) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:504) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:357) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:286) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]


Please include code, not images of code (or logs): see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. Edit the question and include code fragments.

Something else is going on in your client application. According to your screenshot, you got that error after 2 seconds. So, looks like is removed for some reason, e.g. an exception on sending. You can turn on trace logging level for the org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp category to observe some activity from the client in that TcpOutboundGateway.

So, I found something related on stack overflow. I figured to use collaborating adapters to receive from and respond to client (serviceA) and outbound gateway to send and get a response from the server (serviceB). I am getting the error with outbound socket and correlate response. I can't seem to implement the fix advised in this post below. Infact, I will edit the question again
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568806/spring-integration-tcp-inbound-outbound-adapter-with-non-spring-client

That's too much custom code which is hard to digest. Why you cannot just use TcpInboundGateway and TcpOutboundGateway in your Service B to call Service C? The Service A could also just use a TcpOutboundGateway. This way a reply from Service C would come back to that TcpInboundGateway. This one would relay the reply back to its connection up to the Service A. Not sure why you need collaborating channel adapters since looks like that does not work for you.

@ArtemBilan, I trust you had a great day. I have taken your advice to use outbound gateway and inbound gateway, but the error is now no output or channel reply header. I feel like I am closer. I have edited the question. Kindly review it. Cheers

The request-reply pattern in Spring Integration is implemented via Return Address EIP: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ReturnAddress.html.
So, when we produce message downstream from the Inbound Gateway, the replyChannel header is populated.
That AbstractMessageProducingHandler in your stack trace is able to extract this header from the request message to deliver reply properly to waiting gateway session.
So, essentially we don't need gateway.setReplyChannel(backToPos()); on the Inbound Gateway at all. I even have an opened issue to remove its support altogether: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3985.
So, that your service activator could be simpler:
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "forUpslReplyChannel")

No any outputChannel at all. This would optimize not only your code, but runtime behavior since there won't be necessary in extra bridge between real reply channel and respective header value.
However it turns out that request message for this forUpslReplyChannel does not have replyChannel header any more. Apparently you have some other steps in between tcpOutboundGateway and processResponseMessageFromUpslForPurchase. So, you create a new Message but lose headers from request message.
The TcpOutboundGateway does not do that by itself because its logic like:
/**
 * Subclasses may override this. True by default.
 * @return true if the request headers should be copied.
 */
protected boolean shouldCopyRequestHeaders() {
    return true;
}

I believe a debug logging level for the org.springframework.integration category (or WireTap with LoggingHandler subscriber) is a good way to track what is going on with your message when it travels through the flow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/channel/configuration.html#channel-wiretap

Thank you @Artem. It works now. Please I am trying a connection to an external server using SSL. I think I have done everything rightly, but I get a "no subject alternative error name".  This is the link to it, I shared the error logs too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78744719/how-to-solve-the-spring-tcp-ssl-no-subject-alternative-names-present
