How to solve the SPRING TCP SSL No subject alternative names present
I am trying to connect to a server using the TCP outbound gateway via SSL. I am making use of a ClientConnectionFactory. I implemented this
I also am using a custom TcpNetSSLSupport where I am trusting all certificates for testing sake. This is the flow I want to use.
I am getting a "No subject alternative name error". Please what am I doing wrong?
I noticed that when this call is done without Spring Integration Tcp i.e. when I create a socket in a method and do a direct client connection to an external server using SSL while trusting all certificates, there is no error/exception thrown.
@Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory nibssClientConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory =
                new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("196.6.103.10", 55533);
        factory.setSerializer(customIsoMessageSerializer);
        factory.setDeserializer(customIsoMessageDeserializer);
        factory.setSingleUse(true);
        DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport defaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport = new DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport(customTcpNetSslContextSupport);
        factory.setTcpSocketFactorySupport(defaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport);
        return factory;
    }


@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "tcpNibssOutgateChannel")
    public MessageHandler tcpNibssOutboundGateway() {
        TcpOutboundGateway gateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        gateway.setConnectionFactory(nibssClientConnectionFactory());
        gateway.setUnsolicitedMessageChannel(unsolicitedChannel());
        return gateway;
    }


//CustomTcpNetSSLContextSupport
@Component
public class CustomTcpNetSslContextSupport implements TcpSSLContextSupport {

    @Override
    public SSLContext getSSLContext() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException{
        SSLContext result;
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new X509Certificate[0];
                        }

                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }

                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }
                    }
            };

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            result = sslContext;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create SSL context", e);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

Exception stacktrace
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names present
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:925) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readNBytes(InputStream.java:409) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readAllBytes(InputStream.java:346) ~[na:na]
    at com.redtech.terminalmanagement.services.transactionManagement.utils.CustomIsoMessageDeserializer.deserialize(CustomIsoMessageDeserializer.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.redtech.terminalmanagement.services.transactionManagement.utils.CustomIsoMessageDeserializer.deserialize(CustomIsoMessageDeserializer.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.getPayload(TcpNetConnection.java:149) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper.toMessage(TcpMessageMapper.java:176) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper.toMessage(TcpMessageMapper.java:63) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.InboundMessageMapper.toMessage(InboundMessageMapper.java:43) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.receiveAndProcessMessage(TcpNetConnection.java:215) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:206) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:142) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:101) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:458) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:432) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:1475) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1442) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638) ~[na:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted

2024-07-13T19:50:41.542+01:00 ERROR 17516 --- [terminal-management] [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Tcp Gateway exception

However the below works
socket(ipAddress, port, byteToBeSent, true);

private String socket(String ipAddress, String port, byte[] byteReq, boolean isSSL) throws IOException {

        DataInputStream dIn = null;
        DataOutputStream dOut = null;
        String st = null;
        try {

            if (!isSSL) {
                Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, Integer.parseInt(port));

                dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                dOut.write(byteReq);
                st = dIn.readLine();

                log.info("st {} is {}", isSSL, st);

                dOut.close();
                dIn.close();
                socket.close();
            } else {
                TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                        new X509TrustManager() {
                            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                                return new X509Certificate[0];
                            }

                            public void checkClientTrusted(
                                    X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                            }

                            public void checkServerTrusted(
                                    X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                            }
                        }};
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                SSLSocketFactory factory = sc.getSocketFactory();
                SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(ipAddress, Integer.parseInt(port));
                //Socket socket = new Socket("196.6.103.10", 55533);

                dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                dOut.write(byteReq);
                st = dIn.readLine();

                log.info("st isSsl true is {}", st);

                dOut.close();
                dIn.close();
                socket.close();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new TmsIsoException("Socket connection exception after sending stream to host");
        }
        return st;
    }


The certificate you are using does not have any Subject Alternative Names (SANs). For about the last 5 years they are required in certs. SANs contain FQDNs or IP addresses. Create a self-signed cert with a SAN or two. You probably need to use OpenSSL rather than Java keytool

@JohnW: keytool {-genkeypair,-gencert}has supported-ext san:` since Java 7 approx. 2011. Although technically JSSE will still accept the correct name in CommonName if SAN is absent, as was usual practice until about 2010 and permitted by browsers until abouit 2015. But I see no reason to think the server is in Java -- this Q is only about the client. And it might not use OpenSSL either, e.g. MS IIS.

This question is similar to: Certificate for  doesn't match any of the subject alternative names. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Hakan54, read the question again. This question is asked in the context of Spring Integration TCP. I have stated that I am trusting all certificates as this is not production stage. The link you provided talks about someone actually creating a certificate.

The issue is the same regardless of spring. The server certificate is missing the San field and therefore throwing this exception. So the issue is that the server you are reaching to has not the San field configured correctly

@Hakan54, when I create a socket in a method and apply the trust all certificate implementation for SSL connection, I can successfully connect to the remote server and get a response.  But in the context of Spring TCP Integration, the error is thrown

I guess the best way to show that this question is different from the dup is to create a self-signed cert that has a correct SAN, and show that the connection is still rejected because your customized SSLContext is not used.

To solve this, I found from the documentation that I can disable verifying host checkup. See here
connectionFactory.setTcpSocketSupport(new DefaultTcpSocketSupport(false));

So, my abstract client connection factory appears this way
@Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory nibssClientConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory =
                new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("196.6.103.10", 55533);
        factory.setSerializer(customIsoMessageSerializer);
        factory.setDeserializer(customIsoMessageDeserializer);
        factory.setSingleUse(true);
        DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport defaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport = new DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport(customTcpNetSslContextSupport);
        factory.setTcpSocketFactorySupport(defaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport);
        factory.setTcpSocketSupport(new DefaultTcpSocketSupport(false)); //added this line
        return factory;
    }


@Hakan54 When you read the original question, you will see this "I also am using a custom TcpNetSSLSupport where I am trusting all certificates for testing sake. This is the flow I want to use." I AM RUNNING IN A TEST ENVIRONMENT. The question was not a "production environment use case". I like to think that an answer is correct when it answers the question asked.
